# Cocoa left column menu

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, nstableview

Several mac applications, both Apple and third party, feature a menu in the left column usually used for filtering content. Below are some examples from iPhoto, iCal and iTunes.

[image][image][image]

I don't see an interface builder class that corresponds to this. How are these usually implemented? A NSTableView with custom cells? Is there any pre-written code to handle the more complex aspects like the collapsing triangles? This seems like a such a common user interface that I don't want to reinvent the wheel if I don't have to.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Check out [PXSourceList](http://github.com/perspx/PXSourceList).  It's just what you're looking for.